# ng2-charts : Newly added rows not getting displayed on phone devices

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, ng2-charts, angular-chart

I have horizontal bar chart that takes a huge amount of data. Stack blitz link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-chart-hdq41q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).
Problem is as I add more rows, **only on phone layout** the last few rows are not displayed. But it works fine on a desktop screen.
I am dynamically increasing the chart parent divs height, could that be a problem ?


Steps to reproduce the error

1. Open the stackblitz link I have provided,
2. Open the app in a different window
3. Open developer tools
4. Switch to phone device view mode
5. add more rows

After a certain count, the rows are not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Quick Answer : This happens because canvas gets overloaded with large number of rows.
More on this in this [thread](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/1249). This is not an issue with the library.

As per my requirement, I have implemented pagination. I'm loading 10 rows at a time.

If Someone finds an actual solution for this requirement Kindly let me know.

There was a similar question on a vertical bar chart [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63299071/ng2-charts-chart-js-bar-chart-columns-fail-to-render-above-a-certain-width).